# How to set HttpResponse to HttpResponseMessage in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net web `API` application hosted using `OWIN`. The web `API` application uses an external library which depends on `System.Web` and writes its response on System.Web.Response object. I have set a dummy object to `HttpContext.Current` and after that the I expect the external library would set the response at `HttpRequest`. Then I need to know how I could transfer the result from `HttpRequest` to `HttpRequestMessage` so that the web `API` method could process the result.

Here is some sample code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
{
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()));
    httpResponse.Write("From HttpResponse");

    return responseMessage;
}
```

I have written some text using the `HttpResponse.Write()` method, now I need to move the result from `HttpResponse` to `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: Probably you might need to post some code.

Comment: May be its just me..I still dint get what you are looking for. In your question, you talk about transferring result from Request to HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: The result "From HttpResponse" is set at the HttpResponse object, but web api uses HttpResponseMessage to give response to the client. So I need to know how I can I read the response from HttpResponse and set it to HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Comment: We could use MVC if it is needed, but we cannot use System.Web since our application is hosted using OWIN and not hosted in IIS.

Comment: If I'm not wrong MVC relies on System.Web unless its DotNet Core

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is IHttpActionResult see link:
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

Here is an example of how to create a HttpResponseMessage:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
   HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = "From HttpResponse";
   return new ResponseMessageResult(responseMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "{data to return here}")
```

Comment: obviously if the request failed, return the appropriate status code instead of "OK"

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
   if (yourCondition)  
   {  
      return Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);  
   }  
   else  
   {  
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found");  
   }
```